# PostgreSQL: Why is NOT NULL not working here?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.3

I'm developing my first ever application with PostgreSQL.

## The Scenario

**This is what my table "person" looks like:**

```
   Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('person_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name | character varying(255)      | not null
 last_name  | character varying(255)      | not null
 email      | character varying(255)      | not null
 password   | character varying(255)      | not null
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "person_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "person_email_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
    "person_id_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "access" CONSTRAINT "access_person_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(id)
```

This was created using migrations in [knex.schema](http://knexjs.org/#Schema).

If I run the following query in psql...

`insert into person (first_name, last_name, email, password) values ('Max', 'Mustermann', '', '123123123');`

I get back `INSERT 0 1` and the row is successfully inserted:

```
id | first_name | last_name  |               email               |    password    |       created_at        |       updated_at
----+------------+------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------------------
12 | Max        | Mustermann |                                   | 123123123      |                         |
```

## My Question:

**I expect the operation to fail, because no e-mail (NOT NULL) was specified. Why does it not fail?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Max

Comment: `null` and `''` are not the same thing. If you excluded email from your insert completely it would throw an error

Comment: The empty string is not the same as `NULL` (except in Oracle).

Comment: If you want to disallow empty strings too then add `check(email <> '')` or `check(length(email) > 0)`.

Comment: *"lack of a value" is not the same thing as "a value of zero"; similarly, "lack of an answer" is not the same thing as "an answer of no"* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Comment: Ah, I see, for some reason I thought '' was NULL in SQL. Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some DBMS (like Oracle) treats empty string (`''`) as `NULL`. Others (like MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc) treat empty string and `NULL` as different.

PostgreSQL treats `''` as empty string, not `NULL`, so your `insert` statement executed successfully.

Comment: But, postgreSQL will display a NULL where in fact the value is `''` if the column type is string

Answer (score 2):

`null` and an empty string are not the same values, by passing in an empty string you have satisfied the requirement.

If you query was

```
insert into person (first_name, last_name, password) 
values ('Max', 'Mustermann', '123123123');
```

then an error would be thrown because you are not passing in a value for email

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't pass a null value.  You passed an empty string.